# Inner function performance in lua

Tags: performance, function, lua, lua-table, lookup-tables

I have a list with special users and normal users. Special users have their own special func, while normal users use a standard func.

I came up with this code design, but I feel that this is not optimal (performance wise).

**So my question is:** How would I get the best performance when calling inner functions like the example below?

```lua
if something then
  CallFunc(var)
end
```

---

*Special/normal user logic*

```lua
function CallFunc(var)
  if table[name] then 
    table[name](var)
  else
    Standard_Func(var)
  end
end

local table = {
["name1"] = function(var) Spec_Func1(var) end,
["name2"] = function(var) Spec_Func2(var) end,
["name3"] = function(var) Spec_Func3(var) end,
...
--40 more different names and different funcs
}
```

---

*Special user funcs*

```lua
function Spec_Func1(var)
--lots of code
end

function Spec_Func2(var)
--lots of code
end
...
--more funcs
```

---

**EDIT:**
see @hjpotter92's answer:

I cant find the user in the table.

```lua
local function_lookups = {
  name1 = Spec_Func1, --this doesnt let me find the user
  --name1 = 1 --this does let me find the user (test)
}

if function_lookups[name] then --this fails to find the user
  --do something
end
```

Comment: Probably `Spec_Func1` is defined after your lookup table?

Comment: facepalm..........

Comment: Do special users all referred to the same function? Do normal users are all referred to the same function? Are these functions called during the same action? If these conditions are true your job gets a lot easier.

Comment: @warspyking All normal users refer to the same func. Special users all have their own func

Comment: @richardavalos Are they fired in the same situation? E.g both the special and normal user must do the same thing to fire their function?

Comment: @warspyking yes

Comment: I posted my solution, it's clean, simple, requires less code and memory, and is very easily extendable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need another anonymous function. Simply use the lookup table as follows:

```
local function_lookups = {
  name1 = Spec_Func1,
  name2 = Spec_Func2,
  name3 = Spec_Func3,
  ...
  --40 more different names and different funcs
}
```

Do not use the variable name `table`. It is a [library available](https://devdocs.io/lua~5.3/index#6.6) in Lua itself, and you are overwriting it.

Comment: See my edit. Why cant I find the user with your solution?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a special function at all! You can use a generic function that's behaviour depends on the caller! Lemme explain with a piece of code:

```
local Special = {Peter=function(caller)end} --Put the special users' functions in here
function Action(caller)
    if Special[caller] then
        Special[caller](caller)
    else
        print("Normal Action!")
    end
end
```

So whenever a user does a certain action, you can fire this function and pass a caller argument, the function then does the work behind the scenes determining if the caller is special, and if so what to do.

This makes your code clean. It also makes it easier to add more than 2 user statuses!

Comment: This looks like a nice solution, but I if I want to dynamically create special action funcNames from a string depending on whether a caller is special or not (e.g. action = "SpecialFunc_"..caller.name), It would require me to call the function in the global namespace like:  _G[action](), which is not performance-friendly. So in the end I still need a table with all the special func names or put all logic inside your block of code (e.g. if caller.name == "Peter" then specialFunc_Peter() end ..etc).

Comment: @richard Updated, but I feel like there's a more elegant solution. What's different about the normal user, and each of the special users' statuses?